# Delete n lines in the up direction in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a command in vim which will delete **n** lines in the up direction.

I know I can use `4dd` which will delete 4 lines downwards.

Comment: You can combine d with any motion command.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460268/yank-n-lines-upwards-without-moving/5460995#5460995 just use `:d` instead of `:y`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In VIM, 3dk would delete 4 lines in the upward direction. Further documentation can be found at http://www.vim.org/docs.php

Comment: Good point, I missed that but needs to be 3dk, 4dk will delete 5 lines.

Comment: I guess you meant `upward`. Actually 4dk deletes the current and the 4 lines above it.

Comment: You're right, 3j is downward... guess I should take my own advice and read the docs myself!

Comment: @chriskievit, you can edit your answer to correct it. Just click the edit link below it.

Answer (score 17):

V3kd would do it.

Thats "V" to enter visual line select mode, "3k" to move up 3 lines, and then "d" to delete the 4 lines you have selected.

Comment: This is a more accurate answer. `4dk` is not an upward version of `4dd`, but of `4dj`, removing the 4 lines above and below the current line respectively, but not the line itself. `4dd` actually removes the current line 4 times, and this results as the current line and the 3 below.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a backwards range.

```
:-4,.d
```

Deletes from minus 4 lines to current. But this is an ex mode command.

Comment: Same deal as with `d4k` - this deletes one line too many.  You actually want `:-3,.d` to delete 3 lines above *and* the current line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Position the cursor where you want to begin cutting.
2. Press v (or upper case V if you want to cut whole lines).
3. Move the cursor to the end of what you want to cut.
4. Press d.
5. Move to where you would like to paste.
6. Press P to paste before the cursor, or p to paste after.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste

Answer (score -13):

1. stand at the end of the last line
2. hold <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and wait until the last character of the first line is deleted