# vim: yank lines above the current line together with the current line

Tags: vim

I find myself doing `Nyy` very often to yank the current line and `N-1` lines below. So `3yy` would yank the current line and 2 more lines (so all together 3).

I know how to yank `N` lines above the current line (`yNk`), but this does not include the current line. What I want is to yank the current line and `N-1` lines above. How do I do this (ideally also with the `yy` command)?

Edit: Apparently `yNk` includes the current line as well. I must have missed it. Thx for the comments.

Comment: I did mean `Nyy` actually. Sorry, my mistake. I edited my question. Typing in vim is already so automatic that I forget the actual command. :D

Comment: Similar post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460268/yank-n-lines-upwards-without-moving/5460995#5460995

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following will yank the current line plus two above:

```
2yk
```

Obviously changing the `2` will alter the number of lines yanked above. No number is an implicit `1`, so `yk` is equivalent to `1yk`.

Comment: Or `y2k` if you're into conspiracy theories.

Comment: The opposite order feels more natural to me: `yk`, `y1k`, `y2k`, etc.  Follows the general pattern of <command> <movement>.

Comment: Made a mistake in my original question, edited it. Though your answer is sufficient for me. Thanks. @kev/@ephemient y2k just yanks the two lines above the current one, but not together with the current line. Still would be cool if there is way to just do it with `yy`. :D

Comment: @Torsten ... are you testing these? `y2k` definitely yanks the current line and the two above it.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I should have not tested it inline. The code blocks looked to similar so it looked to me it didn't.